How can I ensure that my CSS styles are applied correctly when generating PDFs from a Blade view using dompdf in Laravel?
I'm working on a Laravel application where I need to generate PDFs from Blade views. I'm using dompdf through the barryvdh/laravel-dompdf package. While the PDF generation works, I am having issues with the CSS styles not being applied correctly in the generated PDF.
Here’s how I’m currently generating the PDF:
public function getInvoice($view, $data)
{
    $pdf_font = PdfFont::where('is_active', 1)->first();
    $pdf = PDF::loadView($view, compact('data', 'pdf_font'))->setPaper('a4', 'portrait');
    return $pdf->download("invoice-{$data->invoice_no}.pdf");
}


In the view file sale::sale.pdf, I include a CSS file like this:
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/main-style.css">

owever, the styles do not appear in the generated PDF. The same view renders correctly with styles when viewed in a browser, but the styles are missing in the PDF output.
What steps can I take to ensure that the CSS styles are applied correctly in the PDF? Are there specific configurations or methods in dompdf that can help with this issue?
Thank you!
Despite these efforts, the styles are still not correctly applied in the PDF output. I expected the PDF to render with the same styles as the web view, but the styles are missing or not rendered correctly.

I hope my answer will help you (I had a similar issue with this)
I solved this problem by putting the css inside <style>...</style> tags and it's working fine.
Also if you use some different fonts you need to install those fonts and put them inside the local storage/fonts.
Load them using @font in the in-page css <style>
